# MVC3 Error Page and Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo` the only type of model the `HandleErrorAttribute` is able to pass?

```
[HandleError(View="MyErrorPage")]
public ActionResult Index()
```

Is there a way I can pass my own model class to error page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending HandleErrorInfo? That way you would still be passing a HandleErrorInfo instance, with your customizations.